# VectorPlot NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to VectorPlot (StreamPlot) 2 equations from NDSolve but it doesn't work and I don't know what is wrong. Can somebody please help me?

```
n0 = 10000; s0 = n0 - i0 - e0;
β = 1.5; i0 = 1; e0 = 50; r0 = 0; a0 = 0; α = 1/3; 
muI = 1/2.85; muA = 1/4.1; delta = 0.071;
eps = 1/1.25;
p1 = 0.7;

sys = NDSolve[{
   s'[t] == (- β* s[t]/n0 )*(delta*a[t] + i[t]),
   e'[t] == (β* s[t]/n0 )*(delta*a[t] + i[t]) - eps *e[t], 
   i'[t] == p1*eps *e[t] - muI* i[t],
   a'[t] == (1 - p1)*eps *e[t] - muA* a[t],
   r'[t] == muI* i[t] + muA* a[t],
   s[0] == s0, e[0] == e0, a[0] == a0, i[0] == i0, r[0] == r0}, {s[t],
    i[t]}, {t, 0, 120}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 10]; 

s = (s[t] /. sys) /. t -> s1;

i = (r[t] /. sys) /. t -> i1;

VectorPlot[{s, i}, {s1, 0, 1}, {i1, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `Flatten` `sys` to eliminate an extra pair of parentheses, delete the three lines of code that follow, and then use `ParametricPlot[{s[t], i[t]} /. sys, {t, 0, 120}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]`.  It makes no sense to use `VectorPlot` because both functions depend on the same independent variable.